# La phrase « Je saurais gré à l’un d’entre vous de ramener un tire-bouchon » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions, locutions

Je n'ai jamais vu une phrase avec *savoir gré* sans pronom avant *savoir* (e.g. « je vous saurais gré »). Peut-on dire : « Je saurais gré à l’un d’entre vous de ramener un tire-bouchon » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La phrase est correcte : le *vous* usuellement utilisé avant savoir est remplacé par *l'un d'entre vous*, situé après.

Mais il vaut mieux utiliser *rapporter* quand il s'agit d'un objet et utiliser *ramener* pour les être vivants que l'on mène avec soi :

*L'expression [savoir gré](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gr%C3%A9)* avec *a* : [« Savoir gré, savoir bon gré, un gré infini *à* qqn (de qqc.) »  ( --> § D. 2 )]

> Je saurais gré *à* l’un d’entre vous de *rapporter* un tire-bouchon.

*L'usage de [savoir gré](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/savoir-gre-a3763460)*

> Je vous saurais gré *de* bien vouloir me rapporter un tire-bouchon.

Comment: J'annule ma modif qui je pense soulève un problème important qui mérite d'être détaillé. Comme le remarque *radouxju*, cette formulation peu usuelle qui peut paraître bénigne, n'est pas nécessairement correcte.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai complété ma réponse, la formule est correcte dans la locution *savoir gré à qqn de qqc*.